# How do I prove that there exists this vector?

Tags: linear-algebra

[image: This is the problem]

I am completely lost on this problem and am not sure even where to start.

Comment: Do you know about dual vectors? You can try showing that every dual vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$ corresponds to a dot product with one factor fixed.

Comment: Another approach (although a cumbersome one) is to figure out the coordinates of $T$ by evaluating on the elements of an orthonormal basis. Then $z$ is determined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is much easier than it looks.

Expanding by the first row we have $T(x)=\begin{vmatrix}x_1 & x_2 & x_3 & x_4 \\ u_1 & u_2 & u_3 & u_4 \\ v_1 & v_2 & v_3 & v_4 \\ w_1 & w_2 & w_3 & w_4\end{vmatrix}=x_1\begin{vmatrix}u_2 & u_3 & u_4\\ v_2 & v_3 & v_4 \\ w_2 & w_3 & w_4\end{vmatrix}-\dots-x_4\begin{vmatrix}u_1 & u_2 & u_3 \\ v_1 & v_2 & v_3 \\ w_1 & w_2 & w_3\end{vmatrix}$

Now compare that with $z\cdot x = x_1z_1+x_2z_2+x_3z_3+x_4z_4$. You just take $z_1=\begin{vmatrix}u_2 & u_3 & u_4\\ v_2 & v_3 & v_4 \\ w_2 & w_3 & w_4\end{vmatrix}$, $z_2=-\begin{vmatrix}u_1 & u_3 & u_4\\ v_1 & v_3 & v_4 \\ w_1 & w_3 & w_4\end{vmatrix}$, $z_3=\begin{vmatrix}u_1 & u_2 & u_4\\ v_1 & v_2 & v_4 \\ w_1 & w_2 & w_4\end{vmatrix}$, $z_4=\begin{vmatrix}u_1 & u_2 & u_3\\ v_1 & v_2 & v_3 \\ w_1 & w_2 & w_3\end{vmatrix}$